# Engine functions: Calling MATLAB from a C application

Tags: c, matlab-engine

I'm trying to call a user-defined MATLAB function from a C application, but I'm having trouble getting even the simplest engine scenario to work. Below is a program that should simply print `a = 1` into the MATLAB command window. But when I run it, nothing happens!

```
#include "engine.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{ 
  Engine *ep; 

  if (!(ep = engOpen("\0"))) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't start MATLAB engine\n"); 
    return EXIT_FAILURE; 
  } 

  engOutputBuffer(ep, NULL, 0); 

  engEvalString(ep, "a = 1"); 

  engClose(ep); 
  return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug your code? What do you see?

Comment: I removed engine and matlab tabs and put matlab-engine, which probably gets you more interested visits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdout output is not sent to the MATLAB Engine console. You can specify your own output buffer using

```
char engOutput[300];
engOutputBuffer(ep, engOutput, 300);

engEvalString(ep, "disp('test')");
```

You will then have to print `engOutput` yourself.

If the purpose of the print is just to verify the engine is working, you can go to the engine console and type "a" to see that the variable was created.